# An error occurred in AWS Lambda when I tried to use java library on Node.js runtime

Tags: java, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I want to use library called [Aspose.Cells for Node.js via Java](https://www.npmjs.com/package/aspose.cells).

I uploaded aspose.cells and java library to Lambda Layer and coded simple program which worked perfect on my local machine.

```
var java = require('java')

var aspose = aspose || {}
aspose.cells = require('aspose.cells')

exports.handler = async (event) => {
  // import XLSX file
  var workbook = new aspose.cells.Workbook('input.xlsx')

  // export PDF file
  await workbook.save('output.pdf')
}
```

But when I tested this code, an error occurred. below is the logs.

```
Function Logs
2023-01-28T08:31:42.286Z    undefined   ERROR   Uncaught Exception  {"errorType":"Error","errorMessage":"libjvm.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory","stack":["Error: libjvm.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory","    at Object.Module._extensions..node (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1057:18)","    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:863:32)","    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:708:14)","    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:887:19)","    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)","    at Object.<anonymous> (/opt/nodejs/node_modules/java/lib/nodeJavaBridge.js:21:16)","    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:999:30)","    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10)","    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:863:32)","    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:708:14)"]}
2023-01-28T08:31:44.200Z    undefined   ERROR   Uncaught Exception  {"errorType":"Error","errorMessage":"libjvm.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory","stack":["Error: libjvm.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory","    at Object.Module._extensions..node (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1057:18)","    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:863:32)","    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:708:14)","    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:887:19)","    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)","    at Object.<anonymous> (/opt/nodejs/node_modules/java/lib/nodeJavaBridge.js:21:16)","    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:999:30)","    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10)","    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:863:32)","    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:708:14)"]}
START RequestId: af8c4f10-0288-42e0-8cd3-4337b734cb7e Version: $LATEST
Unknown application error occurred
Runtime.Unknown
END RequestId: af8c4f10-0288-42e0-8cd3-4337b734cb7e
REPORT RequestId: af8c4f10-0288-42e0-8cd3-4337b734cb7e  Duration: 2131.62 ms    Billed Duration: 2132 ms    Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 16 MB
```

Though I don't much familiar with AWS Lambda, in the first place,  is it possible to use java library on Node.js runtime ?

If it isn't possible, are there any way to use Aspose.Cells on AWS Lambda?

thanks

I searched for about two days but I never solved this problem.
I want to use Aspose.Cells on AWS Lambda.

Comment: If you can use any other (Node.js) JAVA library on AWS lambda, so you can surely use Aspose.Cells for Node.js via Java. By the way, you can use Aspose.Cells for .NET on  AWS lambda as tested, see the document (https://docs.aspose.com/cells/net/how-to-run-aspose-cells-in-aws-lambda/) for your reference.

PS. I am working as Support developer/ Evangelist at Aspose.

Answer (score 0):

I hit this issue too after battling with some bundling issues that aspose.cells has due to using node addons. I think this issue may then be due to the AWS Lambda runtime image not having jdk/jre installed to run the Java side of the aspose API. I think you would likely need to extend that AWS runtime image and add in what is required (Oracle JDK). It would be great if the aspose team could provide some samples of running the nodejs wrapper in Lambda like they do with .Net